# How to plot keys from a python dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in the following format:

`{'2021-06-27 ': 2, '2021-06-26 ': 1, '2020-07-25 ': 6, '2020-07-24 ': 2, '2021-01-26 ': 2, '2021-01-24 ': 2, '2021-01-25 ': 1, '2021-03-28 ': 2, '2021-03-27 ': 2}`

I want to make a trend/bar graph to visiualize the quantity at each date. How would I go about creating this?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'2021-06-27 ': 2, '2021-06-26 ': 1, '2020-07-25 ': 6, '2020-07-24 ': 2, '2021-01-26 ': 2, '2021-01-24 ': 2, '2021-01-25 ': 1, '2021-03-28 ': 2, '2021-03-27 ': 2}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'2021-06-27 ': 2, '2021-06-26 ': 1, '2020-07-25 ': 6, '2020-07-24 ': 2, '2021-01-26 ': 2, '2021-01-24 ': 2, '2021-01-25 ': 1, '2021-03-28 ': 2, '2021-03-27 ': 2}

plt.bar(d.keys(), d.values())
plt.show()
```